# Is it okay for a ViewModel class implementing LifecycleObserver?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

Reading the [ViewModel overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#additional-resources), I wonder if it is okay for a `ViewModel` to simultaneously become a `LifecycleObserver` too? My point doing that is to disconnect the Firebase listener when user's not interacting with the UI and reconnect it again when the user's interacting with the UI. As far as I have done and know, it works perfectly. But, I'm afraid if it's bad to do so (memory leaks whatsoever). And if so, is there an alternative to that?

```
class UserProfileViewModel : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ProfileViewModel"
    }

    private lateinit var mUserProfile: MutableLiveData<DocumentSnapshot>
    private var mRegistration: ListenerRegistration? = null

    override fun onCleared() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCleared")
        disconnectListener()
    }

    fun getUserProfile(): LiveData<DocumentSnapshot> {
        if (!::mUserProfile.isInitialized) {
            mUserProfile = MutableLiveData()
        }
        return mUserProfile
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun connectListener() {
        Log.d(TAG, "connectListener")
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "User not signed in.")
            return
        }
        val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val docRef = firestore.collection(UsersContract.COLLECTION_NAME).document(user.uid)
        mRegistration = docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to fetch user data", exception)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                mUserProfile.value = snapshot
            }
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun disconnectListener() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnectListener")
        mRegistration?.remove()
        mRegistration = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not concerned about having the listeners scoped to resume/pause. You can achieve this with a custom live data. 
You can have a custom livedata like UserProfileLiveData which extends livedata.

Refer to Extend Live Data - 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata

Comment: Will the custom `LiveData` has a `ViewModel` as a property?